# How to work with parametrised Shiny R HTML output element

Tags: r, shiny, eval, shinyapps

In my shiny app I am using multiple parametrised variables that depend on a csv configuration file that lists all the IDs needed for the shiny HTML output elements.

In my ui the process is very easy. I do as follows:

`htmlOutput(outputId = paste0("Variable",y))`

where y is the looping variable over the IDs

The problem is on the server side of the shiny app when i want to render this HTML element. The way how I am currently doing so is using the eval parse method. The biggest drawback of that solution is that it consumes a lot of time (in addition to a higher difficulty in reading the R code). An example of rendering the above object:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0("output$Variable",y,"<-renderText({return(paste(\"<div style=\\\"text-align: center;\\\">\",",result,",\"</div>\"))})")))
```

Is there any other more efficient way to render parametrised variable names on the server side of my Shiny App?

I tried to use get and assign functions but neither of them worked.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean you need to do `output[[paste0("Variable",y)]]` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes many thanks! I'm still a beginner with R shiny...